# How to validate conditional form fields in React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am new to React and I was trying to create a functional SignIn form component that changes its structure based on a boolean prop which can be toggled between Login and Signup.
In the signup version, there is an additional text field `Confirm password` which needs to be validated with the password field for a match.
The following is the validation function for the component.

```
export function SignInForm({login}) {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({});
  const [error, setErrors] = useState({});

  const validate = (values) => {
    console.log(login)
    let errors = {}
    if (!values.email) {
      errors.email = "Email address is required";
    } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(values.email)) {
      errors.email = "Invalid email address";
    }
    if (!values.password) {
      errors.password = "Password is required";
    } else if (values.password.length < 2) {
      errors.password = "Password should be 2 or more characters";
    }

    if (!values.confirmPass) {
      errors.confirmPass = "This field is required";
    } else if (values.confirmPass !== values.password) {
      errors.confirmPass = "Passwords do not match";
    }
    return errors;
  }
  
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.persist();
    setValues(values => ({ ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }));
  };

  const submitChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setErrors(validate(values))
  }
...
```

And the following is the returning JSX.

```
<form className={classes.form} onSubmit={submitChange}>
            <TextField
              variant="outlined"
              margin="normal"
              required
              fullWidth
              id="email"
              label="Email Address"
              name="email"
              autoComplete="email"
              autoFocus
              value={values.email}
              onChange={handleChange}
              error={Boolean(error.email)}
              helperText={error.email}
            />
            <TextField
              ...
              value={values.password}
              onChange={handleChange}
              error={Boolean(error.password)}
              helperText={error.password}
            />
            {!login && 
            <TextField
              ...
              value={values.confirmPass}
              onChange={handleChange}
              error={Boolean(error.confirmPass)}
              helperText={error.confirmPass}
             
            />}
```

"..." attributes are common to the first TextField, the remainder of the form is not shown as they are not part of the problem.

When running the Signup version (login == false), the confirm password field stays at "This field is required" even when I am putting values inside it. It does not perform the validation. But the other fields validate just fine.

What am I doing wrong here? And how can I fix this problem? Any lead would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: this is because, the `values.confirmPass` even if not assigned to any element, is empty in the state, and if is empty it gives that error

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```js
if(!login) {
  if (!values.confirmPass) {
    errors.confirmPass = "This field is required";
  } else if (values.confirmPass !== values.password) {
    errors.confirmPass = "Passwords do not match";
  } 
}
```

Since when login is false, values.confirmPass is empty.

Comment: it shouldn't be if(!login) ?  so that it works only when is on signup  ?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I wanted to say, sorry. I already edit it. Thanks!

Comment: This still does not work. On submission, the error I get is "this field is required", even when the field is filled

Comment: Apparently it was my fault. the `name` tag should have the same name as the `values` property name. For confirm password, `value={values.confirmPass}` and `name="Confirm password"` did not match. changing both to `confirmPass` worked.

Comment: Well, good that you were able to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for you piece of code is

```
if(!login) {
  if (!values.confirmPass) {
    errors.confirmPass = "This field is required";
  } else if (values.confirmPass !== values.password) {
    errors.confirmPass = "Passwords do not match";
  } 
}
```

There is another problem that you should set the initial state of your components

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    confirmPass: null,
    password: null,
    email: null,
  });
  const [error, setErrors] = useState({
    confirmPass: null,
    password: null,
    email: null,
  });
```

I do have a good suggestion for you, try to use something to control your forms just like [formik](https://formik.org/) and a schema validation like [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup). Your code will be much more clear and easy to maintain